# Default username/password for Ubuntu Cloud image?

Tags: 12.04, cloud, openstack

I have downloaded and launched an instance of this image in `OpenStack`

http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/13.10/release-20140226/ubuntu-13.10-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img

But I don't know the password of this. Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 13):

There is no default username/password for the ubuntu cloud image. Need to configure it using below cmd, before creating instance from the image.

```
virt-customize -a bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img --root-password password:<pass>
```

Need to install below pkg to get `virt-customize` cmd.

```
sudo apt install libguestfs-tools
```

Comment: The library and tools seem to have split, for me the package was `guestfs-tools`

Answer (score 1):

From OpenStack import or create a key pair and when you launch the instance select the keypair to add. You will be able to "ssh -i your-priv-key ubuntu@your_machine_ip"

PS don't forget to set a security group for the instance to allow ssh connections

Reference: https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/latest/user/configure-access-and-security-for-instances.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no default password, here is how you can set it: [How to set a password for Ubuntu Cloud Images (ie. NOT use ssh)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507345/how-to-set-a-password-for-ubuntu-cloud-images-ie-not-use-ssh/1094189#1094189)