# password for cloud images?

Tags: password, cloud

what is the password for the "ubuntu" and/or "root" user on the cloud images?

i see this has gone unanswered for a while:
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-18-04-ova-cloud-username-password/8933

i am using the bionic ova in this case:
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/bionic/current/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova

here is someone using openstack that also needs password:
[Default username/password for Ubuntu Cloud image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451673/default-username-password-for-ubuntu-cloud-image)

EDIT: I am using virtualbox, not vmware, but i do see there is functionality when using vmware to set the password on initial deploy, so i will try that...... so i guess the answer is cannot use ubuntu cloud images on vbox, as image needs cloud-init to create loginable users.

Comment: This is not a question for Ask Ununtu.

Comment: or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53373376/4424636) to a similar question on SO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm fairly certain there is no default password for either `root` or `ubuntu`.

If you download the cloud-image and mount the root file system without booting it you will see that `/etc/shadow` contains no password for `root`.

The `ubuntu` user does not even exist.  `cloud-init` will create users on first boot.  If you do not provide configuration for `cloud-init` then the default user configuration is used.  That is defined in `/etc/cloud.cfg` as

```
   # Default user name + that default users groups (if added/used)
   default_user:
     name: ubuntu
     lock_passwd: True
     gecos: Ubuntu
     groups: [adm, audio, cdrom, dialout, dip, floppy, lxd, netdev, plugdev, sudo, video]
     sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
     shell: /bin/bash
```

This creates the `ubuntu` user with password login disabled.

Comment: so how do I ssh to it ?

Comment: @sagi the most official option is probably to use `cloud-init` to configure a password or ssh-key.  In certain scenarios other options might be appropriate, e.g. using `virt-customize`.